# Trying to call a common function from jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

My script isn't working when I'm trying to call a common javascript function. How could I do to get it to work? Thanks!

```
$(".displayControl a").click(function() {
    $(".displayControl a").removeClass("activeButton");
    buttonNumber = $(".displayControl a").index(this);
    $(".displayControl a:eq("+buttonNumber+")").addClass("activeButton");
    ShowBoxes(buttonNumnber);
});
```

Comment: what is exactly the error? what is the message of your js console?

Comment: which function `howBoxes(buttonNumnber)` ?

Comment: I hope its not a typo in your code "buttonNumnber" instead of buttonNumber

Answer (score 2):

You could do like below:

```
$(".displayControl a").click(function() {
    $(".displayControl a").removeClass("activeButton");
    ShowBoxes($(this).addClass("activeButton").index());
});
```

---

```
buttonNumber = $(".displayControl a").index(this);
```

should be `buttonNumber = $(this).index();`

and

```
$(".displayControl a:eq('+buttonNumber+')").addClass("activeButton");
```

is just `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

Edit like this

```
buttonNumber = $(this).index();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
$(".displayControl a").click(function() {
$(this).removeClass("activeButton");
buttonNumber = $(this).index();
$(".displayControl a:eq('+buttonNumber+')").addClass("activeButton");
ShowBoxes(buttonNumber);
});
```

Note the line, where I have edited the quotes.

Noted from the comments that their was actually a typo in your function name.